# Why might a comment turn red on approval?

Tags: comments

Weird question here, but I'm hoping somebody is familiar with the issue.

When an admin clicked on the "approve" link under a comment on the comment moderation screen, the entire comment row turned red. The comment did publish--but the "approve" link was still appearing in the list of actions links (when it should have changed to "unapprove"). After refreshing the comments moderation page, everything went back to normal.

Not exactly an important issue. But I need to be able to explain why it happened, and I can't reproduce it (though I believe it happened--she sent me a screenshot). Any thoughts? Anybody seen this before? Is this maybe a common UI convention in WP when AJAX calls fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured, so I'm closing this question out.

Here was the problem: on comment approval, I had some custom stuff hooked, and this custom stuff was throwing an error. This error was being included as part of the comment approval's AJAX response.

It turs out that on listings pages in the admin, if WordPress encounters an unknown AJAX error , it deliberately turns the offending row red. You can see the color being explicitly set in wp-includes/js/wp-lists.dev.js in the function "ajaxDim".